# Adjustments from one cube to another

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have two cubes lets say c1,c2 and I have to make adjustments from c2 to c1

In c1 I have

| loan_id | basis_adjutment | participant_pct |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2345 | 123 | 346 |

In c2 I have

| loan_id | adj_element | txn_amt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2345 | bal | 678 |
| 2345 | bal | 984 |
| 2345 | bal | 2435 |
| 2345 | gain | 676 |
| 2345 | gain | 7689 |
| 2345 | gain | 234 |

When adj_element = bal i should take the corresponding txn_amt and print in basis_adjutment and When adj_element = gain I should take the corresponding txn_amt and print in participant_pct. the joining keys is loan_id The output look like

| loan_id | basis_adjutment | participant_pct |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2345 | 123 | 346 |
| 2345 | 678 | 676 |
| 2345 | 984 | 7689 |
| 2345 | 2435 | 234 |

in total there should be 4 rows( 1 row from c1 and 3 rows from c2 no additional rows. ) can anyone help me out how I can achieve this in  hive

Comment: how come 123 is coming in your result for `basis_adjutment` ? Shouldn't it be 678, 984 and, 2435 ?

Comment: the row coming from cube c1 is  the original row for that  we are adjusting 3 more rows from cube c2

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this SQL -

```
select loan_id, basis_adjutment,    participant_pct from c1
union all 
select distinct -- distinct will ensure no duplicates
c1.loan_id, 
case when adj_element = 'bal' then txn_amt end basis_adjutment, 
case when adj_element = 'gain' then txn_amt end participant_pct 
from c1
join c2 on  c1.loan_id =  c2.loan_id
```